# How to run an application and send file names?

Tags: c#, openstreetmap

I've donwloaded the following maps:

```
andorra-latest.osm.pbf       https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/andorra-latest.osm.pbf
azores-latest.osm.pbf        https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/azores-latest.osm.pbf
cyprus-latest.osm.pbf        https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/cyprus-latest.osm.pbf
```

I need to merge the above maps. So I am using [osmconvert](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert#Windows) to merge maps. I read [this answer about merging maps](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/48843/merging-two-or-more-geographical-areas-to-import-two-or-more-osm-files-in-nominatim).  So if I copy the following command and paste into `command window`, then it works fine - it creates `all.osm.pbf` file:

[image]

So desired file `all.osm.pbf` is created:

[image]

However, now I would like to call this command programmatically. I mean, I would like to call the above command through C#. So I've tried this code in my Console application:

```
static Process process = new Process();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(process_OutputDataReceived);
    process.ErrorDataReceived += new System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler(process_ErrorDataReceived);
    process.Exited += new System.EventHandler(process_Exited);

    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"osmconvert.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"osmconvert.exe andorra-latest.osm.pbf --out-o5m | osmconvert.exe - azores-latest.osm.pbf | osmconvert.exe - cyprus-latest.osm.pbf -o=all.osm.pbf";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    process.Start();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
}
```

But I always see the following error:

[image: enter image description here]]

My files are located in `D:\Downloads`:

[image]

Could you say, please, what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I've tried this code, however, the error is the same:

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Downloads\osmconvert.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"D:\Downloads\osmconvert.exe D:\Downloads\andorra-latest.osm.pbf --out-o5m | D:\Downloads\osmconvert.exe - D:\Downloads\azores-latest.osm.pbf | D:\Downloads\osmconvert.exe - D:\Downloads\cyprus-latest.osm.pbf -o=D:\Downloads\all.osm.pbf";
```

and this approach:

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\\Downloads\\osmconvert.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"D:\\Downloads\\osmconvert.exe D:\\Downloads\\andorra-latest.osm.pbf --out-o5m | D:\\Downloads\\osmconvert.exe - D:\\Downloads\\azores-latest.osm.pbf | D:\\Downloads\\osmconvert.exe - D:\\Downloads\\cyprus-latest.osm.pbf -o=D:\\Downloads\\all.osm.pbf";
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Start the process for three files? Pipe the output to another executable? Because the pipes don’t make any sense here. If you just want to start the executable with three files then start them one after another

Comment: Try passing a full or relative path to your maps, not just the file name.

Comment: You need to put the full path name of all files and folders.  The Process class starts with a null environmental PATH so it is not finding the executable.

Comment: @scai thank for your response. How can I give relative maps?

Comment: @Learner Try passing `D:\\Downloads\\azores-latest.osm.pbf` instead of `azores-latest.osm.pbf`.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen please, see my updated answer. I've tried to clarify my question.

Comment: @scai I've tried, however, the error is the same.

Comment: It’s not about paths. It’s about the pipes. You’ll need to run it through cmd.exe if you want to pipe everything to each other. `Process` doesn’t do that. Or just give all file names at once to the command at once, that should work?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I've tried to write like this `osmconvert andorra-latest.osm.pbf azores-latest.osm.pbf cyprus-latest.osm.pbf -o=all.osm.pbf`. However, it throws an error `osmconvert Error: more than one.pbf input file is not allowed`. Maybe you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are sending `osmconvert.exe` as the first command line argument. The executable is probably trying to open *itself* and process it as map data. That likely fails because it is trying to be opened in a way (read/write) that isn't possible when it is also executing.

Instead, you could "programatically" invoke cmd.exe and tell it to execute the commands:

```
static Process process = new Process();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    process.Exited += new System.EventHandler(process_Exited);

    // create a cmd.exe process.
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.Start();

    var input = process.StandardInput;
    // tell cmd.exe to do your bidding.
    input.WriteLine("osmconvert.exe andorra-latest.osm.pbf --out-o5m | osmconvert.exe - azores-latest.osm.pbf | osmconvert.exe - cyprus-latest.osm.pbf -o=all.osm.pbf");
    // then tell it to exit.
    input.WriteLine("exit");
    // process.Exited event should fire at this point.
    // or you could process.WaitForExit() instead.
}
```